# Missing packages with python-xbee library and raspberry

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyserial, missing-data, xbee

I'm trying to send some packages from an MSP to a Raspberry Pi 3 through 2 Xbee S1 modules.

Xbee are configured as DigiMesh 2.4 with escaped frames, one as router and other as coordinator. At the raspberry the connection is made with USB dongle.

My code, at MSP, sends a package at every 10 us with CTS flow control. When the coordinator is plugged into my PC running windows, I can see, through XCTU, all packages arriving, everything just fine!!!

But, when the dongle is at raspberry, running Raspbian and the following code, some packages can not arrive.

As everything works properly with XCTU, the problem resides in the code, probably handling serial port or anything similar to that.

So, any help would be much appreciate!!!

start.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# copyright: Thiago Cruz <thiagoalberto@gmail.com>

import sys
import os

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from middleware.QueueMiddleware import QueueMiddleware
from jobs.ScheduleJob import ScheduleJob


def startQueue():
    queue = QueueMiddleware()
    queue.start()

def assyncSchedule():
    schedule = ScheduleJob()
    schedule.run()

def runApp():
    startQueue()

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) 


    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    runApp()
```

QueueMiddleware.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# copyright: Thiago Cruz <thiagoalberto@gmail.com>

import threading
import time
import serial
import Queue

from middleware.DataProcessorGear import DataProcessorGear
from xbee import ZigBee

minutes = 0

class QueueMiddleware(threading.Thread):
    __instance = None

    PORT = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
    BAUD_RATE = 9600

    # The XBee addresses I'm dealing with
    BROADCAST = '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xFF\xFF'
    UNKNOWN = '\xFF\xFE' # This is the 'I don't know' 16 bit address

    def __new__(cls):
        if QueueMiddleware.__instance is None:
            QueueMiddleware.__instance = super(QueueMiddleware, cls).__new__(cls)

        return QueueMiddleware.__instance

    def __init__(self):
        QueueMiddleware.__instance = self
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.dataPacketsQueue = Queue.Queue()
        # Create API object, which spawns a new thread
        self.ser = serial.Serial(
                                    port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
                                    baudrate = 9600,
                                    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                                    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                                    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                                    timeout=1
                                )
        self.xbeeApi = ZigBee(self.ser, callback=self.message_received, escaped=True)
        print 'start queue'

    def __del__(self):
        # halt() must be called before closing the serial
        # port in order to ensure proper thread shutdown
        self.xbeeApi.halt()
        self.ser.close()
        self.processor = None

    def run(self):
        # Do other stuff in the main thread
        while True:
            try:
                time.sleep(1)
                #if self.dataPacketsQueue.qsize() > 0:
                #    lock = threading.Lock()
                #    processor = DataProcessorGear(self.dataPacketsQueue, lock)
                #    processor.start()
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                break

    def message_received(self, data):
        global minutes

        minutes += 1
        print minutes
        self.dataPacketsQueue.put(data, block=True, timeout=None)
```

I already tried to change the values of time.sleep() and have suppressed the execution of the subsequent threads to "isolate" the problem.

My console displays values from ~120 to ~170. MSP only sends 200 data packages!!

So... any guesses ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Enable hardware flow control and change the baudrate from 9600 to 115200.  You'll have to update your XBee module configuration for the new baudrate, but you'll stand a chance of getting your packets through.

I assume you meant to write that you're sending packets every 10ms instead of every 10us.  At 10ms/packet, you're at 100 packets/second.  9600 baud is only about 960 characters per second, and your packets are surely larger than 9 characters with the API overhead.

Comment: In fact I send a package and then wait 10us... Tried to change the baud rate and nothing changed.. I forget to mention that my coordinator is a XBee S2C...

Comment: Additional ideas: Test your Python code on a PC to see if a faster computer can keep up.  Switch to using regular API mode instead of escaped API mode to reduce overhead of escaping code.  See if you can keep up without queuing the received data.  Change the sleep() to 0.001 (you mentioned changing it, but not the range of values -- 0.001 = 1ms) to ensure that the sleeping isn't halting all threads.

Answer (score 0):

**Kind of a solution.....**

After trying different approaches in my code, even tried the script below...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial

serialport = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 115200, timeout=None,rtscts=True,dsrdtr=True)

while True:
    serialport.flush()
    command = serialport.readline()
    print str(command).encode('hex')
```

I was able to get a **desired behavior** by changing the  XBee MR parameter (Mesh unicast retries - The maximum number of network packet delivery attempts) to the maximum (0x7), none of my packages are lost, even for a delay of 0s (zero) between the transmission of each package.

Probably, as said by tomlogic, if I run my code on a faster PC, I believe, I'll get my packages.

When I do this test, i'll post the results here.

Thanks.